# How to stop apex methods runs every by clicking lightning button?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, developer-console, developer

After clicking a lightning button processing "changeOwnerCase" method logic but here how we can restrict this method should run only one time instead of running everytime button clicks. Method should executes only one time on first click on button.

Note : Button should be enabled always it will process other operations, Requirement is only - this.changeOwner(); executes on first time button clicks.

Any ideas please ?

LWC HTML

```
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" name="Yes" onclick={submitPopup}  
 label="Yes" style="margin-right: 20px;"></lightning-button>
```

LWC JS

```
import { LightningElement,api, track,wire } from 'lwc';
import changeOwnerCase from '@salesforce/apex/CaseCreationsController.changeOwnerCase';

export default class ET_EMEASecondaryTradingLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    
submitPopup(){
    
        this.isConfirm = true;
        this.handleSubmit(this.event);
        this.changeOwner();
    }
}
```

Apex method

```
@AuraEnabled
     public static boolean changeOwnerCase(String csId){
         boolean returnVar ;     
         Case caseRecord = [select id,ET_Request_Type__c,recordtype.developername,OwnerId,ET_Request_Template__c from Case where id =: csId];    
         if(caseRecord.Recordtype.DeveloperName=='EMEA_FCT'){
           returnVar=  changeOwnerFCTCase(caseRecord); 
         }else if(caseRecord.Recordtype.DeveloperName=='EMEA_Servicing'){
            returnVar =  changeOwnerServicingCase(caseRecord); 
         }
         
         return returnVar;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a boolean variable to track whether the method has been executed or not. You can initialize the variable to false and set it to true after the first execution of the method. Then, you can use a conditional statement to check the value of the variable before calling the method.

For example, you can use this code:

```
// Declare a boolean variable to track the execution of changeOwner()
hasChangedOwner = false;

submitPopup(){

        this.isConfirm = true;
        this.handleSubmit(this.event);
        // Check if the variable is false before calling changeOwner()
        if (!this.hasChangedOwner) {
                this.changeOwner();
                // Set the variable to true after the first execution
                this.hasChangedOwner = true;
        }
}
```

This way, the `changeOwner()` method will only run once on the first click of the button, and not on subsequent clicks.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply , do i need to user thsi variable in html page , hasChangedOwner  anywhere?

Comment: No, you don't need to use this boolean variable in html.

Comment: Thanks I will try once and confirm here