# How to execute apex method only on first button clicks , Restrict apex method calling for further clicks?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, developer-console, developer

I Have a requirement to call the apex method only once after the first click of the lightning button. For the next time button click the requirement to stop calling apex method ones again. For that, I have used some boolean variable but after button clicks still method calls on every button clicks and changes the case owner through the apex method.

LWC HTML

```
<lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" name="Yes" onclick={submitPopup}  
 label="Yes" style="margin-right: 20px;"></lightning-button>
```

LWC Js

```
import { LightningElement,api, track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
import {CurrentPageReference} from 'lightning/navigation';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue }  from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import changeOwnerCase from '@salesforce/apex/CaseCreationsController.changeOwnerCase';
import CASE_OWNER_CHANGED_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.ET_hasOwnerChanged__c';


export default class ET_EMEASecondaryTradingLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    
@track hasChangedOwner = CASE_OWNER_CHANGED_FIELD;

    submitPopup(){

        this.isConfirm = true;
        this.handleSubmit(this.event);

        if (!this.hasChangedOwner) {
            this.changeOwner();
            this.hasChangedOwner = true;
            console.log('Owner Logic Executed---------------->');
      }      
   }
   
       changeOwner(){
     
        this.isLoading = true;
        
        changeOwnerCase({ csId :this.recordId})
        .then(result =>{
           
            const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Case Owner is assigned Successfully',
                variant: 'Success',
                mode: 'pester'
            });
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: this.recordId,
                    objectApiName: 'Case',
                    actionName: 'view'
                }
            });                     
        })
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop apex methods runs every by clicking lightning button?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/412774/how-to-stop-apex-methods-runs-every-by-clicking-lightning-button)

Comment: @TusharJadav, Thanks for the quick response. Eventhough I have changed the code as you suggested but still the apex method calls on every button clicks and changing case owner respectively.

Comment: The code only works when the component is loaded and you click the first time. if you try a second time then the method does not call. But If you reload the component page then the component loads again and the hasChangedOwner variable is set to false. so you can again call the method when click on the button. If you want to restrict the change owner only once then you need to use one custom field to check whether the owner is changed or not. if the field is set to false then you can allow to change the owner and if the field is set to true then not allowed.

Comment: Hi @TusharJadav, I have created ET_hasOwnerChanged__c custom check  box field by default unchecked. The above modified kindly please check let me know if that works

Comment: When you say you want to call this button once, do you mean once in the record lifetime, once after everytime you refresh the page, or reload the page?

Comment: @NagendraSingh, Only for the specific Case I don't want to change the owner again and again. Once owner assigned after first clicks the logic needs to execute and for the next time button clicks it won't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the get record wire method to the JS so you can get the owner change field value from the object record. After that, I have assigned the field value to the `hasChangedOwner` variable. this variable is used to check whether the owner change function is called or not. if the value is false then call the owner change method otherwise it will not call the owner change function.

Use the below code:

HTML:

```
<lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" name="Yes" onclick={submitPopup}  
 label="Yes" style="margin-right: 20px;"></lightning-button>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement,api, track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
import {CurrentPageReference} from 'lightning/navigation';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue }  from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import changeOwnerCase from '@salesforce/apex/CaseCreationsController.changeOwnerCase';
import CASE_OWNER_CHANGED_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.ET_hasOwnerChanged__c';


export default class ET_EMEASecondaryTradingLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    

        // Wire the case record and the field value
        @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [CASE_OWNER_CHANGED_FIELD] })
        caseRecord;

        @track hasChangedOwner = getFieldValue(this.caseRecord.data, CASE_OWNER_CHANGED_FIELD);;

        submitPopup(){

                this.isConfirm = true;
                this.handleSubmit(this.event);

                if (!this.hasChangedOwner) {
                    this.changeOwner();
                    this.hasChangedOwner = true;
                    console.log('Owner Logic Executed---------------->');
                }      
        }
   
        changeOwner(){
     
                this.isLoading = true;
        
                changeOwnerCase({ csId :this.recordId})
                .then(result =>{
           
                    const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Case Owner is assigned Successfully',
                        variant: 'Success',
                        mode: 'pester'
                    });
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    this.dispatchEvent(event);
                    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                        type: 'standard__recordPage',
                        attributes: {
                            recordId: this.recordId,
                            objectApiName: 'Case',
                            actionName: 'view'
                        }
                    });                     
                })
        }
}
```

APEX Method:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static boolean changeOwnerCase(String csId){
        boolean returnVar;     
        Case caseRecord = [SELECT Id, ET_Request_Type__c, Recordtype.DeveloperName, OwnerId, ET_Request_Template__c, ET_hasOwnerChanged__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :csId];  

        if(!caseRecord.ET_hasOwnerChanged__c){
                caseRecord.ET_hasOwnerChanged__c = true;
                update caseRecord;
        }

        if(caseRecord.Recordtype.DeveloperName == 'EMEA_FCT'){
                returnVar = changeOwnerFCTCase(caseRecord); 
        } else if(caseRecord.Recordtype.DeveloperName == 'EMEA_Servicing'){
                returnVar = changeOwnerServicingCase(caseRecord); 
        }
        return returnVar;
}
```

Comment: Code dumps with no explanation are not great answers. If you've made a mistake, it often leads to a chain of comments like "that didn't work" and "try this instead" which are nearly impossible for others to follow. Remember, you're writing this not just for the OP, but also for other people who visit this question with a similar problem.

Comment: @DerekF, I have edited my answer and added the explanation of what I have made the code change.